# Authorization webRequest to MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, webrequest

I have two MVC applications with same login, with same database. I need to get html code from one application with web request. On localhost works fine. But in server not. I need to know, how to set authorization cookies, because I get only html code with login page. I tried it with Forms Authentication. Here is my code:

```
 Uri uri = new Uri(urlAddress);
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);

        var authCookie =
            FormsAuthentication.GetAuthCookie(User.Identity.Name, true);

        // create a new Cookie
        Cookie requestAuthCoockie = new Cookie()
        {
            Expires = authCookie.Expires,
            Name = authCookie.Name,
            Path = authCookie.Path,
            Secure = authCookie.Secure,
            Value = authCookie.Value,
            Domain = uri.Host,
            HttpOnly = authCookie.HttpOnly,
        };

        // add the AuthCookie to the WebRequest
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer.Add(requestAuthCoockie);

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Why you wanna get html from your own app?

Comment: Apps are on differents domains and I do not want to use iframe

Comment: here you are not able to authenticate to the other app, you need to verify cookie you are passing are valid for the other app? you need to check other app authentication policy

Comment: You should explore SSO.